# number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Tags: r

```
sillyplus <- function(x, y) {
    out <- numeric(length = length(x))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) {
        out[i] <- x[i] + y[i]
    }
    out
}
```

A loop at the R level is not vectorized. An R loop will be calling the same R code for each element of a vector, which will be inefficient. Vectorized functions usually refer to those that take a vector and operate on the entire vector in an efficient way. Ultimately this will involve some for of loop, but as that loop is being performed in a low-level language such as C it can be highly efficient and tailored to the particular task.

Consider this silly function to add pairwise the elements of two vectors

```
sillyplus <- function(x, y) {
    out <- numeric(length = length(x))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) {
        out[i] <- x[i] + y[i]
    }
    out
}
```

It gives the right result

```
R> sillyplus(1:10, 1:10)
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: Have you considered "row groups" in datatable? It looks as if you are trying to do that manually.

Comment: Iteratively `rbind`ing to `df` is horrible, and with larger data it always slows down *a lot*. See the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) chapter 2, *Growing objects*.

Comment: The reason I ask is that your method here is inefficient for a few reasons, not just the `rbind`-problem. I don't know if I want to dive into trying to transform this double-`for` loop into a still-not-quite-right `apply` method, or to suggest an overall more-efficient process.

Comment: i come to know apply is faster than for loop thats why i tried that method is it possible to convert that into apply @r2evans

Comment: It *used* to be the case that `for` loops were significantly slower than the `*apply` functions, but around R-3 or so they made some significant improvements.

Comment: ok.. can you please debug the code which i tried @r2evans